# How to avoid instanceof if I can only obtain objects of a certain class, but my method can only work on the sublass

Tags: java, instanceof

Specific Example:
I have a Track class and a Track-switch class that extends the track class.

`class Track {}`

```
class Switch extends Track {
   boolean state;

   void changeState() {
      state = !state;
   }
}
```

I have a Railway class that maps IDs to tracks.

```
class Railway {
   Map<Integer, Track> IDMap = new Hashmap<>();

   void changeSwitch(Integer id) {
      Track temp = IDMap.get(id);

      if (temp instanceof Switch) {
         ((Switch) temp).changeState();
      }
   }
}
```

How do I avoid using instanceof and downcasting in my changeSwitch-method? I have heard of the rule "Tell, don't ask", but it feels very wrong to write a method in Track that just throws an exception. (I intentionally left out modifiers to simplify)

Comment: You can't, you need to assure it ;)

Comment: So is this a case where instanceof is legitimate?

Comment: Absolutely yes ;) you give a instance, and you may assure the type to call a specific method from a subclass , so you NEED to check it

Comment: You can always change your design. For example you may examine if it is possible to write: `Track implements Switchable` and change how `state` is stored.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't have to create method in Track that throws an exception. You can create method that do nothing. Then you can just call changeState for each and every Track in IDMap

Comment: Well that's true, but would it still be considered good practice?

Comment: Talking about good practice, why do you want different types of tracks in the same collection? Maybe it's better to use composition over inheritance and put a reference onto Track object inside Switch. Or if you need to toggle Switch every time train passes particular Track you can create Map<Track, Switch>. Or even create property Track.switch and set it only for tracks with Switches. I would prefer the latter, and just
if (temp.getSwitch() != null) temp.getSwitch.changeState();

Comment: If i get the idea behind the changeState right it's even better to create method Track.pass() and override it in Switch. It maybe useful for Track itself to implement railway block-sections.

Comment: I need them to share the same ID-pool and I have another class IDAdministrator that assigns IDs by certain rules that I use for other classes as well. And the other classes have inheritance properties too.